# ctx.store() redrawing the previous points also

Tags: html, canvas

I am drawing the free hand images on the canvas, everytime I provide an array of points to draw on the canvas, when the 1st set of array passes to the function it draws exact to the points which I haven given ,
But when I pass the 2nd set of array, It draws the 1st array points along with the new set (array2) points,

here is my code

```
function drawManualMarkings(ManualArr) {
        $('#canvascontainer').css('display', 'block');
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvascontainer');
        document.getElementById('canvascontainer').getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, 480, 360)
        for (var i = 0; i < ManualArr.length; i++) {
            if (canvas.getContext) {
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
                if (i == 0) {
                    ctx.restore();
                    ctx.moveTo(ManualArr[i].x, ManualArr[i].y);
                }
                else {
                    // ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    ctx.lineTo(ManualArr[i].x, ManualArr[i].y);
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
            }
        }
```

when i=0 ; and it calls the ctx.strore() it drawing the old image 
how to resolve it please help,
any help will be much use full

Thanks

Comment: Begin each new path with `ctx.beginPath()` or else the previous path will also be redrawn with the new path.

Comment: Thank you so much It's working fine